# Remove emoticons and URL's in R

Tags: r

I extracted tweets from Twitter related to #TrumpCaved!!
In my tweets I wanted to remove the emoticons, url's and all other speacial characters from all the tweets. One of the tweets is as follows:

> @mitchellvii @AnnCoulter Hey all you #MAGA people, how did you like
>   watching @realDonaldTrump cave today?
>   … HTTP content[If I
>   use http link I could not able to post it]

I tried using the following code but it doesn't work for me.

In my scenario, I tried to remove URL's successfully and after I use the next code to remove the emoticons it gets removed but now the URL's gets added. Can anyone help me in removing all the unwanted characters from the text especially the URL's and emoticons?

First I tried to remove the http using gsub function

```
Corpus = gsub("https.*","",  tweets_text$Tweets)
O/p : @mitchellvii @AnnCoulter Hey all you #MAGA people, how did you like watching @realDonaldTrump cave today? <U+0001F602><U+0001F923><U+0001F602><U+0001F923>…
```

Next I tried to remove the emoticons using gsub function

```
Corpus = gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]","", tweets_text$Tweets)
O/P : mitchellvii AnnCoulter Hey all you MAGA people how did you like watching realDonaldTrump cave today  https//tco/vmUCJvTnEO
```